# how do I set get junit to show correct error or exception stack trace

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have noticed when I run a Junit test using maven on the cli when ever there is an error or exception all I get is

```
com.x.blah.testmyclass : tried to access method 
org.apache.maven.surefire.report.SimpleReportEntry.<init>
  (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/maven/surefire/report/StackTraceWriter;)V from class
 org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4RunListener
```

Is there any way to:

1. Get it to print out the actual test that caused the failure within the class
2. Output the original exception that was thrown

I am not very experienced in Maven and have looked around online but can't see anything obvious and have been resorting to logging in my tests when they fail which can be very time consuming

Comment: Looks like they made some changes with 2.19 - not sure if related or not.  http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/logging.html

Comment: So I made that change and it longer spits out the above error message But still doesn't output the actual exceptions... any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, seems to be outputting now. @rafaelim if you wanted to add your comment as an answer I would be happy to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your surefire-plugin version!

maven-surefire-plugin 2.10 has this SimpleReportEntry(String, StackTraceWriter) constructor but in version 2.19 doesn't have it.